# Python: Insert data to database from CSV and then selecting a generated UUID from the table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, csv

I have an Excel sheet that is to be inserted into a database. I wrote a Python script, which takes an Excel file, converts it into a CSV, and then inserts it to the database.

The problem is that the database contains two tables, where one of them has a unique ID which is auto generated and gets set when the data is inserted into the table. The other table uses this as a foreign key.

This is how my tables are created:

```
create table table (
  id             uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  foo1           varchar(255),
  foo2           varchar(255),
  foo3           varchar(255),
  foo4           varchar(255)
);

create table another_table (
  id             uuid PRIMARY KEY references table (id)
  foo1           varchar(255),
  foo2           varchar(255)
);
```

This is the code I use to insert the data into the database:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            cur.execute(
                "INSERT INTO table (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s); ",
                "INSERT INTO another_table (foo1, foo2) VALUES (%s, %s),
                row
            )

conn.commit()
```

This will insert data into the database, but the ID field in another_table will be empty. **Does anyone know how I can acquire this ID and put it into the second table?**

Comment: You may have to change your logic slightly. Here's one way: 1) create a temp table with (foo1, foo2). 2) Join with table t on t.foo1 = tmp.foo1 and t.foo2 = tmp.foo2 to get corresponding uuid. 3) Insert to another_table (t.uuid, t.foo1, t.foo2). This assumes foo1 and foo2 pairs are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself without doing much tweaks with my code. I had to solve another problem with my code where several values in the csv file where null values, but converting to csv made it look like it was empty strings instead. By using pandas I was able to set all null values to "None", and afterwards cleaning each row before inserting it into the database:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            clean_row = []
        for x in row:
            if x == "None":
                clean_row.append(None)
            else:
                clean_row.append(x)
                cur.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO table (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s); ",
                    "INSERT INTO another_table (foo1, foo2) VALUES (%s, %s),
                    clean_row
                )

conn.commit()
```

The values from the csv is now put into an array which I can use in my query to ask table for it' id, like this:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                clean_row = []
            for x in row:
                if x == "None":
                    clean_row.append(None)
                else:
                    clean_row.append(x)
                    cur.execute(
                        "INSERT INTO table (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s); ",
                        "INSERT INTO another_table (foo1, foo2, id) VALUES (%s, %s, SELECT id FROM table WHERE "
        "foo1 = '" + clean_row[0] + "' AND foo2 = '" + clean_row[1] + "')),
                        clean_row
                    )

    conn.commit()
```

This will acquire the ID and put it into another_table, and can be done as long as u have unique values in table.